# How can I create a Bootstrap carousel with autoplay for images and videos?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4, frontend

I'm trying to create a carousel with autoplay with images and videos so I have the following code:

I'm trying to create an autoplay carousel with images and videos with bootstrap 4, jquery and html so I have the following code:

In jquery I try to verify the element that is displayed and the following according to its type update the interval of the slide, apparently it does not find the selector but when using a different order it reproduces the video but the slide no longer changes.

The idea is to have 5 slides when the image has an interval of 5 seconds and then when it is video it has the interval corresponding to the duration of the video and that it is played.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

            let allVids  = $("#myCarousel").find('.carousel-item.video');
            const carousel = $("#myCarousel");
    
            function setCarouselInterval(interval) {
                carousel.carousel('dispose');
                carousel.carousel({
                    interval: interval
                });
                carousel.carousel('cycle');
            }

            setInterval(function() {
                $('.carousel').carousel('next');
            }, 50000);
    
            allVids.each(function(index, el) {
            if (index !== 0) {
                if ($(this).is('video')) {
                    $(this).find('video')[0].pause();
                }
            }
            });
    
            $("#myCarousel").on('slide.bs.carousel', function(ev) {
                // debugger;
                let slides       = $(this).find('.carousel-item');
                let currentSlide = slides[ev.from];
                let nextSlide    = slides[ev.to];
    
                let currentElement = currentSlide.querySelector('img, video');
                let nextElement    = nextSlide.querySelector('img, video');
    
                if (currentElement && currentElement.tagName === 'VIDEO') {
                    let currentVideo = currentElement;
                    currentVideo.pause();
                    currentVideo.currentTime = 0;
                }
    
                if (nextElement.tagName === 'VIDEO') {
                    // debugger;
                    let nextVideo = nextElement;
                    let time      = nextVideo.duration;
                    let interval  = time * 1000;
                    nextVideo.play();
                    setCarouselInterval(interval);
                    
                } else {

                    let intervalAux = 5000;
                    setCarouselInterval(intervalAux);
                }
    
            });
        });
```

```css
 #myCarousel {
        max-width: 960px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        }

        .carousel-control-next, .carousel-control-prev {
            width: 9% !important;
        }

        .carousel-inner {
        background: #FFF;
        }

        .carousel-indicators {
        bottom: -13px !important;
        }

        .carousel-item {
        padding-bottom: 25px;
        }

        video {
        width: 100%;
        }

        .carousel-item .active, video {
            background-color: #FFF
        }

        .carousel-container {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-3qaqj0lc6sV/qpzrc1N5DC6i1VRn/HyX4qdPaiEFbn54VjQBEU341pvjz7Dv3n6P" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-SI27wrMjH3ZZ89r4o+fGIJtnzkAnFs3E4qz9DIYioCQ5l9Rd/7UAa8DHcaL8jkWt" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>test</title>
    
</head>
<body>
 <div class="carousel-container">

        <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-bs-ride="true">
            <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="carousel-item active">
                    <img src="https://img.freepik.com/vector-gratis/fondo-galaxia-dibujos-animados_52683-63638.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="..." width="961" height="664">
                </div>

                
              <div class="carousel-item video">
                <video controls class="myvid" id="player2" width="961" height="664">
                      <source src="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/ElephantsDream.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                      </video>
              </div>
          
              <div class="carousel-item video">
                <video controls class="myvid" id="player2" width="961" height="664" data-interval="16000">
                      <source src="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/ForBiggerBlazes.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                      </video>
              </div>
            </div>
          
            <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
              <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
              <span class="sr-only">Vorige</span>
            </a>
            <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
              <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
              <span class="sr-only">Volgende</span>
            </a>
          </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: You should edit and re-write the question in English, or use the Spanish version at https://es.stackoverflow.com/.

Comment: It seems that the issue was due to not finding the element with the `querySelector` method. Could you provide the HTML code?

Comment: @Sead Thanks, I'll transfer it to English

Comment: @cardosource i just added the html thanks

Comment: replace `if (currentElement.tagName === 'VIDEO')`  with `if (currentElement && currentElement.tagName === 'VIDEO') `

Comment: @cardosource thanks, it doesn't work...
You have edited the question with the code so that the error can be seen